# How to upload GULP project to File Manager / CPanel?

Tags: javascript, html, gulp, hosting, file-manager

It's my first time using Gulp. I am familiar with React.js, Gatsby, Next.js, but I don't know how to upload Gulp project to Hosting. after `gulp build` the only logical thing I see is `production` folder. I have zipped it and uploaded, but the website (hosting) doesn't see it. How to make my project live?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.

1. `gulp build`
2. Zip the `production` folder
3. Upload it to your cpanel under `public_html` folder and unzip it.
4. Make sure you have `index.html`! If you don't, you won't be able to see your website. In my case I had `homepage.html` instead, that was the main problem. Just rename it to `index.html`.